# sequence and series-Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Given

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1 - |x|^n}{ 1 + |x|^n}$$

Find the pointwise limit $f(x)$. Prove that the convergence is not uniform

Ans: I know how to find pointwise convergence
For $|x| < 1, f_n(x) \to 1$ , if $|x| > 1, f_n(x) \to 1$.
 If $|x| = 1$ , 
then $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 1 &\,,\;\;\;\    |x| < 1\\{}\\ 0 &\,,\;\;\;    |x| = 1\\{}\\ -1 &\,,\;\;\;    |x| > 1\end{cases}$$

but how will i show convergence is not uniform
(i need to see detail steps please for Cauchy criterion)-review question

Comment: "A function that is the uniform limit convergence of a sequence of *continuous* functions is..."? BTW, I think the limit function in the case $\,|x|>1\,$ is wrong...check this.

Comment: thats instructor solution

Comment: well the instructor erred somewhere because $f_n(x)=f_n(-x).$

Answer (score 2):

A sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly converges to a continuous function. The  limiting function function $f(x)$ you described is not continuous, so the convergence could not have been uniform.

Comment: [You don't need to restrict to a compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) to get the contradiction. If the $f_n$'s are all continuous on $X$ and if they converge uniformly to $f$ on $X$, then $f$ is continuous on $X$. No matter what the topological space $X$ is.

Answer (score 2):

If the convergence were uniform then the sequence of continuous functions would converge to a continuous function. However, the limit is discontinous which yields the contradiction.